# rails and dalli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

`Rails.cache.read('sessions:session_id') returns nil` even though the same key is being set in memcached (I ran memcached in verbose mode to confirm is the key was being set or not).

Why is it so?

Comment: Can you please provide a code excerpt for the code you are using to set and get the key?  Can you also post your relevant memcached verbose log?

Comment: hi! it turns out that i had been using a namespace in the key...

Answer (score 0):

2 thoughts come to mind.

1. Sessions are lazyloaded, thus it may not have been set until you needed it.
2. Maybe you are setting nil

-daniel